# How to get list of all databases and run query on it in python

Tags: python, mysql, boto

I want to print all databases of 1 RDS and run a select query on it.
Here, I am able to print all databases but want to run SELECT query on each database.
Please suggest solution for it?

```
import boto.rds
import sys
import os
import MySQLdb

conn = boto.rds.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-1", aws_access_key_id='xxxx',aws_secret_access_key='xxx')
instances = conn.get_all_dbinstances()
db = instances[0] 
print "%s %s" % (instances, db.endpoint)
```

I used this as a code, but its not working

```
host_name=db.endpoint
print host_name 

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=host_name,user="dxx",passwd="xxx",db="xxx")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
db.commit()
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
     if row[0].find('em') != -1:
        print row[0]
        sql="select * from row[0].T_USER where LoginId='%s'" % 'hello'
        cursor.execute(sql) 
        results = cursor.fetchone()
        print results[0]
```

Comment: Is it giving any error? What data you expect ?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass dbendpoint as a host, but it showed me TypeError: connect() argument 1 must be string, not tuple

Comment: Just print the `db.endpoint`, its returning you tuple, get hostname form that tuple.

Comment: I am not getting it, do I need to modify it using regular expression or something else?

Comment: What is the output of `print host_name` statement ?

Comment: (u'xxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com', 3306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rds_tut.html

see this page. it useful.

db.endpoint look like this

```
(u'db-master-1.aaaaaaaaaa.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com', 3306)
```

it is python tuple and use like

```
host_name=db.endpoint[0]
```

and print all databases use simple query like

```
show databases;
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I show all databases on 1 rds, because here connect needs db_name but I want to extract this list first and then execute select statement on all